# Is that possible to capture which object on Object reference not set to an instance of an object. error

Tags: c#, asp.net, error-handling, runtime-error

I have an ASP.net website with C#. Current framework is 4.5

I have a global unexpected error catching function.

It is located at global.asax

Here how i catch

```
    void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Code that runs when an unhandled error occurs
    if (Server.GetLastError() != null)
        if (Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException() != null)
        {
            Exception objErr = Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException();
            ErrorLogger.LogError(Request.Url.ToString(), objErr.Message.ToString(), objErr.StackTrace.ToString());
            if (objErr.Message.IndexOf("does not exist") != -1)
            {
                Response.RedirectPermanent("Error404.aspx");
            }
        }
}
```

Now it catches errors and many times there are plenty of information to debug the error. However there is 1 error that i can not get enough information.

It is `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

It doesn't give any information about which object it is. Are there any way to get more information about it ?

Here a typical error

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at gamepage.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

Thank you very much for answers.

Comment: Did you try, you know.. debugging?

Comment: Have you tried debugging ? knowing on which line the problem occurs would already help...

Comment: i would try debugging if know what causes it. there are thousands of visitors who causes these errors :D

Answer (score 3):

A `NullReferenceException` does not carry information about the variable which is `null`, no.

> It doesn't give any information about which object it is.

That's just it... it *isn't* an object.  It's a reference to where an object is expected, but there's no object there.  `null` is literally the absence of information.

The way to handle a `NullReferenceException` is to carefully craft your code so that either:

1. It doesn't happen, or
2. It happens in a potentially expected way, and you check for it and either throw a custom informative exception (which can still be a `NullReferenceException` with simply a custom message) or in some way log/persist the information and meaningfully continue execution of the application.

Since no code or developer is perfect, it's fully expected that from time to time one will slip through the checks and balances.  This is ok.  It *should* be easy to identify which object is `null` in this case.  The stack trace should point to a specific method (perhaps even a specific line of code, depending on what information is available to the runtime) and there *shouldn't* be a whole lot of potential `NullReferenceExceptions` there.  If there are, the method is sloppy and should be cleaned up anyway.

When it happens, identify the object which was `null` by debugging and investigation, and update the code to handle the potential `null` case for that object.

Comment: thank you very much for the answer. the problem is i have no idea what causes it and i checked. stack trace doesn't tell much :( the visitors are causing this error. but thanks for the answer

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG: The stack trace will at least identify the method where the exception is thrown.  There's a finite number of places this could possibly happen in any given method.  (Again, if the method is very large and complex, fix *that* problem first before continuing to diagnose this one.)  If you can reproduce the issue locally, examine the objects in your debugger.  If you can't, add some logging statements to get more information the next time it happens.  Visitors are not causing this error, the code is.  If this error is at all possible, the code needs to be modified to handle it.

Comment: yes it tells it happens at .Page_Load . but page load is pretty big :D it would be nice if i could somehow log locally given object names and could store them on errors.

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG: `"it would be nice if i could somehow log locally"` - You can.  By doing exactly that in your code.  Logging frameworks such as Log4Net make this very easy.  `"but page load is pretty big"` - Then you have two things to fix.  One of them is preventing you from fixing the other.  So it's pretty clear which needs to be fixed first.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could do to help with tracking down the problem would be to find the method that has errored, and possibly even the line of code within that by performing a runtime stacktrace, something like:

```
var st = new StackTrace();
var errorInfo = String.Join("...", st.GetFrames().Select(x => 
    {
        var m = x.GetMethod();
        var t = m.DeclaringType;
        return String.Format("{0}.{1} @ {2}:{3}:{4}", t == null ? "" : t.Name, m.Name, x.GetFileName(), x.GetFileLineNumber(), x.GetFileColumnNumber());
    });
```

that will allow you to find the code and fix it.  I've not used such an approach in a global error trap such as the Application_Error event handler you are using, but I have used this approach to see where calls are coming from in other scenarios successfully, often to track down event handlers that are subscribed to an event.

Comment: thanks these errors are happening on server side where it is published. i don't know your method would work or not since it is published with precompling.

Comment: That is server side code, the precompiling should not lose any of the information gathered here, all the information is in the IL that IIS will be running.  What this will do is allow you to capture the stack trace in the production environment, and using this approach in conjunction with @David's approach will allow you to track down the problem without attaching to the process.  If you do not want to use the open source log4net fr any reason, the semantic logging provided with Enterprise Library is very good also.

Answer (score 0):

Use try..catch when you use any object and throw error with inner exception and stacks trace so you can log that error and get more information about specific error.